# How to update postgres array on Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I selected column "user_list" in 'users' table and fetched to a python variable called "u_list". I appended 'item' in it and tried to update "user_list", but got a lot of errors. I tried searching on stackoverflow, but nothing helped.

code:

```
cursor.execute(f'SELECT user_list FROM users WHERE id=442392434899681280')
u_list = cursor.fetchone()[0]
u_list.append('item')
cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET user_list = {} WHERE id = 442392434899681280'.format(u_list))
data_base.commit()
```

but got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\workspace\sabo\test.py", line 30, in <module>
    cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET user_list = {} WHERE id = 442392434899681280'.format(u_list))
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: UPDATE users SET user_list = ['item'] WHERE id = 4423924348996...
```

Another try and error
code:

```
cursor.execute(f'SELECT user_list FROM users WHERE id=442392434899681280')
u_list = cursor.fetchone()[0]
u_list.append('item')
cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET user_list= (%s) WHERE id = 442392434899681280", (u_list))
data_base.commit()
```

error:

```
  File "d:\workspace\sabo\test.py", line 33, in <module>
    cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET user_list= (%s) WHERE id = 442392434899681280", (u_list))
psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: malformed array literal: "item"
LINE 1: UPDATE users SET user_list= ('item') WHERE id = 4423924348996...
                                    ^
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about it like if you were typing the query yourself. As the error statement specifies, to [PostgreSQL arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) must star with '{' so they will have to be **within curly braces**. If you were to write the query in SQL yourself it would look like this:

```sql
UPDATE users SET user_list = '{"foo", "bar", "item"}' WHERE id = 442392434899681280;
```

### Handcrafted way

So in Python, it would have to be done like this:

```py
cursor.execute(f'SELECT user_list FROM users WHERE id=442392434899681280')
u_list = cursor.fetchone()[0]
u_list.append('item')
cursor.execute('UPDATE users SET user_list = \'{{{}}}\' WHERE id = 442392434899681280'.format(','.join(['"{}"'.format(v) for v in u_list])))
data_base.commit()
```

**Notice the three curly braces in the formatting**, [two are to escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) so one '{' remains an the third is for the formatting. Also, **if your list is not of strings you will have to convert it before joining**.

### Let *psycopg2* handle it

[*psycopg2*'s docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#lists-adaptation) also state that Python lists are converted to PostgreSQL `ARRAY` so the above would be done like like this:

```py
cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET user_list= %s WHERE id = 442392434899681280", (u_list,))
```

You are missing a comma after the list and there is an extra parentheses surrounding `%s` in your code sample.

Comment: psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: UPDATE users SET user_list= {item} WHERE id = 442392434899681...

Comment: Sorry, forgot the single quotes, I'll update the answer.